# NetBeans setting up multiple .o library outputs in a make file?

Tags: c++, netbeans, makefile, shared-libraries, archive

I am new to make files and Linux programming in general, and am having a bit of trouble setting up a Netbeans project/make file to do what I want. My project consists of a bunch of libraries broken into groups that will then be archived together.

To further explain, basically each .cpp file is a individual library that needs to be compiled into a .o file, then all the .o files in each group need to be archived into a .a file. on the command line I would do something along these lines:

```
for i in *.cpp; do g++ -I./ -c $i -o $i.o ; done
```

then:

```
ar -r "libWhatever.a" *.o
```

What I need help with is setting up the make file to output the libraries .o files into the correct group folder and get rid of all the extra folder that it is making. I also would like it to have it automatically archive the library groups together.

My project is set up like this:

```
project -> source - > library_group -> cpp files + sub-folders containing cpp files that are part of the library group.

project -> header -> library_group -> h files + sub-folders containing h files that are part of the library group.
```

In NetBeans I then set up the "Include Directories" under the "Source Files" + "Header Files" properties to include all necessary files and folders.

The project now compiles without a hitch, but it outputs it like this:

```
build -> Debug -> GNU-Linux-x86 -> Project -> library_group -> libraries + sub-folders containing more libraries.
```

What I want is for the output to look like this:

```
build -> Debug -> library_group (this folder should contain all .o files associated with the library group)
```

Any ideas on how to configure the make file to do what I want?

Comment: Where do you want the makefile to reside, and where do you want to run it?

Comment: The make file exsists one level above project folder IE: project_name (make file, and git information) -> project

Answer (score 0):

This may take several iterations; I'll have to guess at a lot.

First, let's try to build a single object file. If one of your source files is `foo/bar.cpp`, and it includes `baz.h` and `quartz/quince.h`, then try this rule:

```
build/Debug/library_group/bar.o : project/source/library_group/foo/bar.cpp
    g++ -Iproject/source/library_group -Iproject/source/library_group/quartz -c $< -o $@
```

and tell us the result.